# TinyMCE image custom hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, tinymce

I'm working with TinyMCE editor with some old webpage content.
All HTML content could contain "links" to images in format "`.. <img src="##IMAGE:1234##"/> ..`".
I need to show image in HTML preview, but in code it has to stay in format "`..<img src="##IMAGE:1234##"/>..`"

I know URL to download/inline all images =>
 http://example.com/images/1234

Do I need to parse editor content, replace IMG src by URL + ID from original IMG src (`##IMAGE:1234##`).

Is there some way, how to have in HTML code mode something like this "`..<img src="##IMAGE:1234##"/>..`", but in preview mode have image displayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE relies on the browser to render the HTML that you give to the editor.  As the current `src` you are providing is not valid the image won't show.

What I would suggest is to use a `data-xxx` to store the value you need and programmatically set the `src` attribute when you place the content into the editor.

For example...

You might store the image tag in your database as `<img data-imgsrc="##IMAGE:1234##" />`.   When you get ready to load the content into the editor add the `src` attribute to the image tag so you end up with `<img data-imgsrc="##IMAGE:1234##" src='http://example.com/images/1234' />`.  This allows the editor to render the images.

When you go to save the HTML content back to the database you can remove the `src` attribute from any image that also has the `data-imgsrc` attribute (assuming you need to do this for some reason).